# Meteor Dynamic Collection Implementation

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am creating dynamic collection in my application but I am not able to fetch, insert and update that dynamic collection.

Dynamic collection created when I am inserting a Record in different collection.
For example I have person collection and want to create dynamic collection of task to dynamically separate task data of every person.

Please help me out how can I implement the same in meteor?

```
var collectionCache = {};
function create_collection(name) {
    collectionCache[name] = new Mongo.Collection(name);

    Meteor.publish(collectionCache[name], function() {
        return global[collectionCache[name]].find();
    });
}
```

My collection name is `task_parentID`.

Now data should saved in `task_parentID` where `parentID` is unique ID of that parent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please share the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm the problem- You want a document to be created in `Task` collection when a collection to be created for that `Person`?

I will advice against thie approach and will recommend you follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612577/create-a-dynamic-meteor-collection-using-a-variable)

To explain:
Create two collections - `Tasks` and `Persons`.

The document inserted in `Persons` will have a unique id. The `Task` can have a structure like this:

```
{ _id : //unique ID
//other fields
assignedTo: //_id of the Person to whom the task is assigned
}
```

The `assignedTo` will contain the `_id` of document in the `Persons` collection.

When you need to sort, just call the subscription as `Tasks.find({assignedTo: _persons_Id});` and you will get all the tasks under the said person.

Comment: No I want to create a new "task_persionId" collection dynamically against new Person document. when I am adding task of that new person, tasks data of that person should go in that collection task_persionId.

Comment: Did you check the link I mentioned? It has advised against creating collections on the fly as '`meteor` is not designed for it. The more efficient approach will be to create a single collection and assign a differentiating id as I have have mentioned and in the link too.

Comment: Yes I already go through that link . Actually I want to handle client data in separate collection due to some security issue, so I require this feature in Meteor

Comment: There you go then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214667/creating-new-meteor-collections-on-the-fly

Comment: Thank You so much for your response.
Yes I already go through that link, With the help of this I am able to create collection dynamic but not able to insert and fetch data from that collection  because collection  name is dynamic. I added meteor dev extension to check mini mongo database included the same dynamic collection in it but I have found it is not included.

Comment: function create_collection(name) {
    collectionCache[name]  = new Mongo.Collection(name);
 
    Meteor.publish(collectionCache[name], function() {
    return global[collectionCache[name]].find();
    });
  }

Comment: my collection name is task_parentID

Comment: now data should saved in task_parentID where parentID is unique ID of that parent

Comment: You should probably comment on the answer in the link. Those guys will be able to assist better.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?  I got some pointer in this directions. Just to diagnose the problem, You said, you were able to create the collections, but were not able to insert? Were you able to insert/read after restarting the server?